# Is this approach better than just firing stream.Read() in a Task.Run?

Tags: c#, async-await, networkstream

Edit: I did not end up doing this approach as per the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464496/5149679) with [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary).  If you are interested in how I did it differently, take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469430/5149679) below.

I'm looking for a way to asynchronously read from a `NetworkStream` with a timeout. Of course, the problem is that there is no way to cancel a `ReadAsync()` on `NetworkStream` as it just ignores the `CancellationToken`. I read an answer which suggested closing the stream on Token cancellation, but in my case that is not an option as the Tcp connection has to remain open. So I came up with the following code, but I was wondering if this is any better than doing a

```
Task.Run(() => stream.Read(buffer, offset, count)
```

and just blocking a thread.

```
public static class TcpStreamExtension
{
    public static async Task<int> ReadAsyncWithTimeout(this NetworkStream stream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        bool keepTrying = true;
        Timer timer = new Timer(stream.ReadTimeout);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, args) => stopTrying(sender, args, cts, out keepTrying));
        timer.Start();

        try
        {
            if (stream.CanRead)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (stream.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        return await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }

                    if (keepTrying)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(300, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cts.Dispose();
                        timer.Dispose();
                        throw new IOException();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException tce)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
        finally
        {
            cts.Dispose();
            timer.Dispose();
        }
        if (stream.DataAvailable)
        {
            return await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        throw new IOException();
    }

    private static void stopTrying(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args, CancellationTokenSource cts, out bool keepTrying)
    {
        keepTrying = false;
        cts.Cancel();
    }

}
```

The application has to potentially be able to communicate with several thousand endpoints and I wanted to create it in a way that it won't block a bunch of threads as most of the work it does is IO.  Also, the case of timing out should be

Comment: You can close the NetworkStream without closing the TCP connection, If you get the stream from a TCPClient don't use it, get the socket and create manually the stream with this overload: `public NetworkStream(Socket socket, bool ownsSocket)` with `ownSocket = false`, in this way it will leave the TCP connection open and you can create as many streams as you need.

Comment: It seems that if stream.ReadAsync throws an exception cts and timer won't be disposed.

Comment: Side note: Make sure you have decent way to reliably find beginning of next message after canceling read operation as you don't know what current state of the steam will be.

Comment: @Gusman thank you very much for the suggestion, however, this approach also seems to result in data loss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464496/5149679) with [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) and his advice, I took a second look at how I might implement this and I went with an approach that does not timeout per read, but it stays open as long as the TcpClient is open and then controlling the timeout from different code. I use `Task.Run(() => beginReading());` so that would of course use threads from the pool but I think it is okay since most of the time that thread will be hitting the `await` and therefore be free

Here is my implementation:

```
private readonly Queue<byte> bigBuffer = new Queue<byte>();
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

// This is called in a Task.Run() 
private async Task beginReading()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    using (_shutdownToken.Register(() => m_TcpStream.Close()))
    {
        while (!_shutdownToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                int bytesReceived = 0;
                if (m_TcpStream.CanRead)
                {
                    bytesReceived = await m_TcpStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    // in case the stream is not working, wait a little bit
                    await Task.Delay(3000, _shutdownToken);
                }

                if (bytesReceived > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < bytesReceived; i++)
                    {
                        bigBuffer.Enqueue(buffer[i]);
                    }

                    _signal.Release();
                    Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LoggingService.Log(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

private async Task<int> ReadAsyncWithTimeout(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    int bytesToBeRead = 0;

    if (!m_TcpClient.Connected)
    {
        throw new ObjectDisposedException("Socket is not connected");
    }

    if (bigBuffer.Count > 0)
    {
        bytesToBeRead = bigBuffer.Count < count ? bigBuffer.Count : count;

        for (int i = offset; i < bytesToBeRead; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = bigBuffer.Dequeue();
        }

        // Clear up the semaphore in case of a race condition where the writer just wrote and then this came in and read it without waiting
        if (_signal.CurrentCount > 0)
            await _signal.WaitAsync(BabelfishConst.TCPIP_READ_TIME_OUT_IN_MS, _shutdownToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return bytesToBeRead;
    }

    // In case there is nothing in the Q, wait up to timeout to get data from the writer
    await _signal.WaitAsync(15000, _shutdownToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // read again in case the semaphore was signaled by an Enqueue
    if (bigBuffer.Count > 0)
    {
        bytesToBeRead = bigBuffer.Count < count ? bigBuffer.Count : count;

        for (int i = offset; i < bytesToBeRead; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = bigBuffer.Dequeue();
        }


        return bytesToBeRead;
    }

    // This is because the synchronous NetworkStream Read() method throws this exception when it times out
    throw new IOException();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, what you're attempting to do is fundamentally flawed. You should be reading from an open TCP/IP stream *all the time* - as soon as one read gets some data, pass that along and start the next read.

So, my first recommendation is to *not* need a cancelable read in the first place. Instead, always keep reading. In the same vein, using `DataAvailable` is a code smell.

More explanation...

There isn't a good way of "enforcing" cancellation on non-cancelable code. Closing the TCP/IP socket is the easiest and cleanest approach. Your existing solution won't work because `ReadAsync` is ignoring the `CancellationToken`. So it's not any better than just using `CancellationToken` without a timer. If `ReadAsync` ignores the `CancellationToken`, your only real option is to close the socket. Any other solution may cause "lost data" - data that is read from the socket but discarded.

Comment: That is the kind of criticism I was looking for.  I will give a try of what @Gusman suggested in the comment and will report on how it goes

Comment: @SvetAngelov: I'm not sure if that would work well. It depends on how `NetworkStream` reads from its `Socket`. Many streams have some kind of buffer, which would cause lost data if the stream is closed and the socket reused.

Comment: I wish I had a way to get around the canceling, but unfortunately the endpoint we are connecting to, a legacy device which is not changing, expects us to try to connect for a certain amount of time and if we get no reply, we are to cancel, then wait a while and try again. I'll see if I can do anything to get around that

Comment: @SvetAngelov: That's a higher-level cancel. You should keep a continuous read going. The "no reply received in a time frame so retry later" logic belongs in a higher level of the code.

Answer (score 0):

For a similar usecase I used a `Task.Delay()` task for timeout.
Looks like this:

```
public static async Task<int> ReadAsync(
        NetworkStream stream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, int timeoutMillis)
{
        if (timeoutMillis < 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(timeoutMillis));
        else if (timeoutMillis == 0)
        {
            // No timeout
            return await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count);
        }

        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var readTask = stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, cts.Token);
        var timerTask = Task.Delay(timeoutMillis, cts.Token);

        var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(readTask, timerTask);
        var hasTimeout = ReferenceEquals(timerTask, finishedTask);
        // Cancel the timer which might be still running
        cts.Cancel();
        cts.Dispose();

        if (hasTimeout) throw new TimeoutException();
        // No timeout occured
        return readTask.Result;
}
```

Comment: I originally went with the same approach but then I noticed that some messages would get lost.  I think what was happening is the readAsync call would remain open and leak messages.

Comment: Once you got into the first timeout and cancel the read you basically have no more guarantee about the state of the stream. There might have been some data already consumed, or there might not. The only thing you can do is close the network stream after any timeout on that layer.

Comment: Actually I tried what Gusman suggested in the comment in the question and that does not seem to work either. Closing just the stream without the client also results in loss of data.